# approval process if price value changes

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
ISCHANGED( Price__c )  <>  PRIORVALUE( Price__c )
```

Hi i am trying to create an approval process using above formula when price value is changed it must enter a approval process.

I am getting an error message "Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula".How can i achieve the functionality.

Comment: Where are you using this formula? Is it in the entry criteria of the approval process?

Comment: yes i am using formula in entry criteria of approval process.

Comment: The entry criteria is executed when the "Submit for Approval" button is clicked. Its not possible to use ISCHANGED as nothing on the record has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The entry criteria is evaluated when the **Submit for Approval** button is clicked. Its not possible to use ISCHANGED as nothing on the record has been changed.

What you would to do is to write a trigger that fires when `Price__c` changes. The trigger would then start the approval process. See [here](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/dynamic-approval-process-based-on-the-apex-and-trigger/) for an example of how to do this.